# Changing colour of a single list item

Tags: html, css

In my page I have a list of hyperlinks which is set as follows;

```
<div id="links">
<ul>
<li><a href= "#"> | CONTACT US | </a> </li> &nbsp;
<li><a href= "#">ABOUT |</a></li> &nbsp;
<li><a href= "#">NEWS |</a></li>&nbsp;
<li><a href= "#">  NEWSLETTER SIGNUP |</a></li> &nbsp;
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is change how the colour of only the "Newsletter Signup" link is set. 
My Css is set as follows;

```
#links ul
{
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
#links ul li
{
 display: inline;
}
        #links ul li a
    {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5%;

    }

#links a:hover
{

 background-color: #04a4cc;
}
```

So far I can only change the colour of all the hyperlinks are set. I've also tried to assign a class to the "newsletter signup" list item like so,
      NEWSLETTER SIGNUP |  
And change the css of the class but I can't even get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change the color of the link try this:

```
 #links ul li:last-child a {
   color: black;
 }

#links ul li:last-child a:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the "Newsletter Signup" is always last, you can do:

`#links ul li:last-child
{
    background-color: "whatever";
}`

or else you should make a class and use it in css

Answer (score 0):

try to use these:

```
#links ul li:nth-of-type(1)
{
 //First Element
}
```

So for Newsletter & Signup you need :

```
 #links ul li:nth-of-type(4)
{
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<div id="links">
<ul>
<li><a href= "#"> | CONTACT US | </a> </li> &nbsp;
<li><a href= "#">ABOUT |</a></li> &nbsp;
<li><a href= "#">NEWS |</a></li>&nbsp;
<li><a href= "#">  NEWSLETTER SIGNUP |</a></li> &nbsp;
</ul>

#links ul
{
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
#links ul li
{
 display: inline;
}
        #links ul li a
    {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 5%;

    }

 #links ul li:last-child a {
   color: green;
 }

#links ul li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
   color: red;
  background: #000;
}
#links a:hover
{
 color: black;
 background-color: #04a4cc;
}
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iHxCv)